# Nagios and Switches NOOB

Tags: monitoring, switch, nagios

I need some help, I want to monitor the DGS-1024D which is a business grade d-link switch.

I have no current way of knowing if any of these have IP addresses on the switch or if there is away to monitor the switches. We also have a master switch which is in our server room, which is a HP J4906A 48-Port Ethernet Switch

I am wondering if anyone else has, monitored a switch and how they have done it, even a cfg file would be good to view to see what I am to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, while the DGS-1024D is (small) "business grade" switch, it is not a managed switch. It has no concept or support for anything Layer 3 or above so there is nothing you can do to monitor it.

The HP on the other hand is managed and completely monitorable using SNMP. 99% of our network is HP Switches and I monitor them all. Each switch model is slightly different though, so you'll need to use tools like snmpwalk to discover what values you care about. Most HP switches IME should be able to give you CPU load, fan speeds and temperatures.

Answer (score 5):

This is not a business grade switch, it's just a cheapish unmanaged device which can't be queried by Nagios as it lacks anything required to do so (like an IP address of it's own or SNMP capabilities or anything). All you can do is monitor one or more devices that are connected to the switch and as long as those devices are reachable you know the switch is not dead.